# Marge subsequent rows pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, series

Hay I have this series:

```
3274
3274
2374
2374
2375
2374
2374
3275
```

Now I want to Marge all the subsequent rows and take the first row(that start the sequence)

For the example above I want the  outcome be this:

```
3274
2374
2375
2374
2375
2374
3275
```

There is a sample way to that instade of iterate the all series and search for sequences?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) wit compare shifted values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df = df[df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift())]
print (df)

    col
0  3274
2  2374
4  2375
5  2374
7  3275
```